# A webBrowser form crashes the app when backed

Tags: codenameone

When I press back button to go from a form with webBrowser component to any other form, it crashes in android. However, it works fine in iOS. Specifically it doesnt work in android samsung galaxy s5(android version 5.0) but works great in simulator and other android devices as well. I am updating the app. It worked great in previously built versions but is giving problem in new builds. I haven't changed anything in the form which makes it crash though.

I tried to debug the device and got following log. I think "Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1" is the main issue here

Log:

```
11-15 14:40:51.278: A/google-breakpad(9135): M A0598000 008F1000 007A1000 000000000000000000000000000000000 data@app@com.capitalEye.roundTable-1@base.apk@classes.dex
11-15 14:40:51.453: A/libc(8864): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 8864 (lEye.roundTable)
11-15 14:40:53.653: E/audit(5364): type=1701 msg=audit(1479200153.653:335994): auid=4294967295 uid=10217 gid=10217 ses=4294967295 subj=u:r:untrusted_app:s0 pid=8864 comm="lEye.roundTable" reason="memory violation" sig=11
```

My code:

```
protected void beforeWebView(Form f) {
    f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    f.getToolbar().setUIID("Container");
    t = new Toolbar();
    t.setUIID("TitleAreaa");
    f.setToolBar(t);
    Style s = UIManager.getInstance().getComponentStyle("Button");
    Image backtoRTN = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_ARROW_BACK, s);

    back = new Command("Back to RTN", backtoRTN) {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            showForm("BusinessForum", this);
        }
    };
    back.putClientProperty("uiid", "BacktoRTN");
    f.setBackCommand(back);
    t.addCommandToLeftBar(back);
}

@Override
protected void postWebView(Form f) {
    if (Connectivity.isConnected()) {
        WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
        if (businessWebsiteUrl != null && !businessWebsiteUrl.equals("")) {
            wb.setURL("http://" + businessWebsiteUrl);
            f.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, wb);
            f.revalidate();
        } 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a system crash from the browser component which is a native peer. I'm guessing the underlying HTML triggered a bug in the webkit code of the native OS triggering that crash.

Since we use the native Android OS browser and VM a system level crash is an Android bug. We can workaround some of those but if it's within the HTML the likelihood of a workaround is slim.

Comment: But it worked when I built & updated the app in playstore about 3-4 months ago. Now the same code is giving problem in new builts. Also what is the workaround?

Comment: Moreover I used f.removeAll() in back command actionPerformed method, now it sometime works and most of the time, app crashes. If we remove browser component on the form, shouldn't it work?

Comment: Did the HTML or the web change in any way? If you have a pro account you can check with versioned build and see if that provides a workaround. It's possible that Android broke some things in the migration to API level 23